# why tan θ > sin θ for range 0 to 90

Tags: trigonometry

(i) Prove the identity $$\tan^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta \equiv \tan^2 \theta\sin^2\theta$$

(ii) Use this result to explain why $\tan θ > \sin θ$ for $0^\circ < \theta < 90^\circ$

I only need the answer for part 2(ii), how tan θ > sin θ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given range $0 \lt \theta \lt 90^\circ, \quad \tan\theta > 0$ and $\sin\theta >0$

From $[i]$, we see that the right-hand side, being the product of two squared values is necessarily positive. So $$\tan^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta > 0 \implies \tan^2 \theta > \sin^2 \theta\tag{1}$$

And as $\tan \theta$ and $\sin \theta $ are both positive in our range, $(1)$ implies that $$\tan \theta > \sin\theta\quad \text{for }\;0<\theta<90^\circ$$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if $0^\circ\lt \theta\lt 90^\circ$, then
$$\sin\theta\gt 0\ \ \text{and}\ \ \tan\theta\gt 0.$$
So, since 
$$\tan^2\theta\sin^2\theta\gt 0,$$
we have
$$\tan^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=(\tan\theta-\sin\theta)(\tan\theta+\sin\theta)\gt 0.$$
Hence, we have
$$\tan\theta-\sin\theta\gt 0\iff \tan\theta\gt \sin\theta$$
because 
$$\tan\theta+\sin\theta\gt 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the left hand side is always positive for $\theta$ in your given range, so what does this say about the difference on the right hand side?